# Using Office365 Excel array formulas, how to calculate ytd totals for all rows and months?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, array-formulas

Can one array formula calculate ytd totals for each month and name?  See desired results.  I tried doing it by row but getting a #calc! error.

[image]

Formula:

```
=LET(data,B5:D7,BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,SCAN(0,r,LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)))))
```

Data:

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| B | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| C | 7 | 8 | 9 |

Comment: Could you please try my second answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another cleaner approach could be using `MAKEARRAY()`. Give a try to the following formula.

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(B2:D4),COLUMNS(B2:D4),
LAMBDA(r,c,SUM(TAKE(CHOOSEROWS(B2:D4,r),1,c))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You getting `#CALC!` because `BYROW()` can't return array output. It can only return single value. Try-

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",BYROW(B2:D4,LAMBDA(rw,TEXTJOIN("|",1,SCAN(0,rw,LAMBDA(a,x,a+x))))),LAMBDA(acc,dt,VSTACK(acc,TEXTSPLIT(dt,"|")))),1)
```

[image]

Comment: @ciso That array means vertical array (array of calculation of rows). I mean it can't return horizontal array.